# menu bar pushes past divs exposing region behind it on window resize

Tags: html, css

I have a webpage with a menu bar, banner (div) and a main section (container div). The menu bar extends past the visible region of the window when the window is resized (made smaller), which triggers the horizontal scrollbar. But if I then scroll to the right in the resized window, the banner and container stay where they are and the background of the website is exposed.

Also I have a min-width enabled right now for the menu bar because I don't want the menu bar pieces collapsing down to the next available line in a messy fashion on resize.

Is there a way to get the bar to collapse in an organized manner on resize, for example: first row with 4 blocks, second row with 3 blocks. Or any other suggestions for how to deal with the menu bar during resize?

I've also had difficulty properly centering the menu bar.

Here is the jsfiddle for the page with the relevant sections of html and css. http://jsfiddle.net/dj99aq6e/

```
 <div id="dtitle">
   <h2 id="title">Title</h2>
 </div>
```

piece of code for the menu bar:

```
<!--menu bar STARTS -->

<ul id="sddm">
 <li><a href="" 
    onmouseover="mopen('m1')" 
    onmouseout="mclosetime()">test</a>
 </li>
```

CSS:

```
body{
font-family: sans-serif;
background-color: #b2b2b2;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2); 
margin:0;
padding:0;
height:100%;
width:100%;
overflow-x: auto;
}

html{
margin:0;
padding:0;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
overflow:hidden;
}

#dtitle{
background-color:black;
padding:0;
height:8%;
width:100%;
overflow:hidden;
border:solid;
border-color: gray;
border-width:0 0 5px 0;
min-height: 60px;
}

#sddm{
display:table;
margin:10px auto;
margin-bottom: 2px;
padding-left: 0;
min-width: 1050px;
z-index:30;
}


#sddm li{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
float: left;
font:14px sans-serif
}

#sddm li a{
display: block;
margin: 0 1px 0 0;
padding: 8px 10px;
width: 128px;
background: #5970B2;
color: #FFF;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none
}


#sddm li a:hover{
background: #49A3FF}

#sddm div{
position: absolute;
visibility: hidden;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background: #EAEBD8;
border: 1px solid #5970B2
}


#sddm div a
{   position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    width: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #EAEBD8;
    color: #2875DE;
    font: 12px sans-serif
}

#sddm div a:hover
{   background: #49A3FF;
    color: #FFF}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I figured it out.

I gave #about (the main content container) a min-width of 1000px, and #dtitle a min-width of 1050px. The 1050px min-width matches the min-width on the menu bar which was the key. Now upon resize and then horizontal scroll the previous gap on the right disappears!

I also put a div around the contact information div and gave it a min-width of 1050px so it stays positioned properly.

Here is the updated code: http://jsfiddle.net/dj99aq6e/2/

```
#dtitle{
background-color:black;
padding:0;
height:8%;
min-width:1050px;
overflow:hidden;
border:solid;
border-color: gray;
border-width:0 0 5px 0;
min-height: 60px;
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are going for? http://jsfiddle.net/dj99aq6e/1/

I took out the `overflow: hidden` from `#dtitle` and adjust the text with padding

```
#dtitle{
    background-color:black;
    padding:0;
    padding-top: 5px;
    margin-top: -15px;
    height:8%;
    width:100%;

    border:solid;
    border-color: gray;
    border-width:0 0 5px 0;
    min-height: 60px;
}
```

Comment: No, the problem is with the menu bar and resize. Your code still leaves a gap on the right side when you resize and then horizontally scroll to the right.